# excel signature per sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a single working excel document rather than multiple documents. The problem is that every document requires 3 signatures. If I merge the documents, each sheet would require 3 signatures.

**The signatures would need to only affect the sheet they are on, rather than the whole document.** For example, if Sheet1 is signed, it cannot be edited, but Sheet2 can still be edited. I do not mind using VBA if that is the best way to do this. I cannot even find a reference to anyone else trying this before... Thank you!

Comment: Signatures are per file not per sheet. So you must split the 3 sheets into 3 files.

Comment: I would rather not split them. I used 3 as an example, but there are close to 20 sheets and it is very tedious to have 20 working documents. I am asking how to make them per sheet instead of per file. I am aware that it is not a built-in solution and it will require some code. I am looking for a reference on where to begin on this, thank you.

Comment: No, that requires Microsoft to change Excel. You cannot change that.

Comment: I have heard of the solution being produced in VBA using custom signatures, but it is a 20,000 lines VBA project, I just want a reference on how to begin. It is ok if you don't have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because signing Excel files is a built in Excel feature that is designed by Microsoft to sign a complete file. Therefore it is not possible to sign a worksheet only.

After a file is signed it is closed for editing:
[image]

For reference: [Add or remove a digital signature in Office files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d).

Comment: I am more looking for a custom signature rather than excel's built in signature. The answer is appreciated though.